# How to add Background Image for PHP file

Tags: php, html, css

How can I add a background image on my PHP file? I want to add an image to the page that thanks my users for subscribing to the newsletter.

I have tried the body background attribute for HTML but it did not work.

```
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <?php

    /* CONNECTION */
    $database_connection = new StdClass();

    /** MySQL hostname */
    $database_connection->server = '829.23.12.123';

    /** MySQL database username */
    $database_connection->username = 'something_usr';

    /** MySQL database password */
    $database_connection->password = 'KJGAout7L';

    /** The name of the database */
    $database_connection->name = 'database_content';

    /* ESTABLISHING THE CONNECTION */
    $database = new mysqli($database_connection->server, $database_connection->username, $database_connection->password, $database_connection->name);

    if($database->connect_error) {

      echo 'connection failed';
    }

    $stmt = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO Email_Subs (email) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST[email]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    echo "<div class='jumbotron text-xs-center bg-white'>";
    echo "<h1 class='display-3'>Thank you, you have successfully subscribed!</h1>";
    echo "<p class='lead'>You will be the first to hear about news, events, exclusive stories, and more!</p>";
    echo "<p class='lead'>";
    echo "<a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='index'>Return to Home</a>";
    echo "</p>";
    echo "</div>";

    $database->close();

    ?>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTML `<style>` tag to add a background image:

```
echo "<style> body { background-image: url(\"https://www.example.com/image-here.jpg\"); } </style>";
```

Comment: What if its a local file and not a link?

Comment: that is not a problem at all, if the file path is correct on you local; it ok